# How many Questions can I edit in a bulk before they are reviewed?

Tags: discussion, editing, review, suggested-edits

I like to edit question and answers by new users, but I don't have edit privileges. So every time I edit a couple of posts I receive this message:

[image: Screenshot]

I just want to know

- How many posts I can edit in a row before getting this?
- How does peer review system actually work?
- Why does it take a long time usually? (no offence to peer reviewers, I'm just curious and not complaining.)

Comment: For a long time I have wanted to thank you for doing so many edits. It's a huge service to the site. Thank you so much! I have also wanted to mention that there is one way that I think you could improve your edits. The main one is that when you make a hyperlink, it should be informative; the naked link at least allows the reader to see the domain and sometimes the article title. The hyperlink should be as informative as the naked link - show the article title at least.

Comment: If the link is to an Ask Ubuntu question it is automatically rendered into the question title - please don't edit those as removing the title makes it harder for readers to see what the link is. If we can avoid clicking links (because we can see what they are) or at least get an idea of their relevance before clicking, that's one less diversion on the way to providing an answer or understanding a solution. Occasionally I rejected your edits for this reason and I hate rejecting good faith edits.

Comment: I'll surely look into that and it's my pleasure to help! I. Didn't want to say it and I don't even know if saying this is right or not but **it's feeling really great to read two huge paragraphs about myself, it's just an amazing feeling** and I want to learn proper ways of editing posts, can I learn it from a post at meta? Or something?

Comment: :D You are doing a great job of editing. Imho the best way to get better at something is to keep practising & get feedback. Unfortunately the edit review system gives us extremely limited scope to give feedback, but if you go to look at the post after the edit has been reviewed, sometimes you can see the reviewer has "improved" (or possibly rejected) and done further/different editing. I learned some tips that way. Also, editing is a community responsibility - your edits do not have to be perfect - anyone can suggest or carry out further edits. Between us all we can get it just right :)

Comment: My advice for you now is to please stop making edit summaries just "made it easier to read." Give us some detail as to what you did ("added code tags"), please. Otherwise, keep up the great work.

Comment: @KazWolfe i'll take a note of that, these comments are really helping me, it's good to know that people **notice** here

Comment: haha @KazWolfe I see *much* worse edit summaries. And I am much too lazy to write edit summaries unless I want to [communicate with the post author](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/907139/4). The only thing that bothers me in suggested edit summaries is when someone writes something *rude* about the post. If the edit really needs an explanation eg "added info from comments" or "previous edit changed backticks into quotes!" then summaries are important, otherwise, \*shrug\*.

Comment: Actually though, one other thing to make even more awesome edits (sorry to bombard you with pings) is, when you make an image visible, to use the hyperlink syntax so it is clickable `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` (and on another line you need `[1]: https://image.ext` of course)

Comment: @Zanna I never understood the difference between those two, finally I went with whatever was easy, now I realise that easy path was indeed the wrong one, note taken. and keep bombarding me with pings, it's already starting to positively effect how I do these things.

Comment: I have another suggestion for your edits. When you find an image that is _not_ uploaded to imgur (URL looks like `https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tH8U.png`) then find that image and upload it. I just did a _lot_ of image corrections for dead image links on Super User because people had posted screenshots from other image hosting sites that are either totally gone, or their accounts are closed and the images are gone. SE has worked something out with imgur so that the images will always be there for us.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver i've seen some broken links too, nice suggestion, thanks

Comment: If you find a broken link try searching for that link, and/or the question/answer itself, on the web archive, AKA "The Wayback Machine", at https://archive.org/web/ I have rescued nearly 4 dozen images from there.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver   [archive.org/web](https://archive.org/web/) bookmarked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to the first question is five.

For how the review works you can see [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)

Edit reviews don't take long. Currently, there are two pending edits in the queue. Two users with at least 2k rep can approve a suggested edit, or if a reviewer chooses to <kbd>improve</kbd> an edit it is immediately approved.

> [image]

Other reviews, close votes or flags, can take days because it takes five 3k users to do one review. Also, there are hundreds of them.

> [image]

I am pleased you are keen to edit but you are still <2k rep and review is there to make sure people don't rush edits and make low quality posts. In short, it is working well ;).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways an edit can be approved including.

1. The original poster of the answer will get notified of your edit, they can approve your edit on their own regardless of their reputation level.
2. A user with 2K rep looking at the review queue or spotting the "(1)" next to the edit button selects selects "improve edit". When they submit their improved edit both the original edit the original edit will be automatically approved.
3. A user with 2K rep looking at the review queue or spotting the "(1)" next to the edit button selects "approve". In this case it takes two users to approve the edit before it goes through.

How long it takes varies a lot depending on whether the original poster is active, whether anyone is bothering to look at the review queue and whether your edit is a simple one that is obviously good or one that actually changes the meaning of the post and needs consideration by someone with a good understanding of the question and answer.

Keep contributing at your current rate and you will soon reach 2K rep and then your edits will go through without review.